# qtcpserver qsocketnotifier: invalid socket and type 'Read', disabling solo falla en producción

Tags: socket, debian, virtualbox, qt5

Llevo varios días de cabeza con esto. Tengo un Servidor que acepta conexiones de clientes (c++ con Qt5), para ello tengo un QTcpServer del cual conecto la señal "newConnection()". Cuando recibo esta señal saco el socket:

```
        while (server->hasPendingConnections())
    {
        QTcpSocket *socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
        connect (socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()), this,SLOT(slotReadyRead()));
        connect (socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(slotDisconnected()));
        QByteArray *buffer = new QByteArray();
        buffers.insert(socket, buffer);
        sendAck(socket);
    }
```

Tengo una tabla hash (buffers) en la que guardo el buffer del socket, con el socket como índice, y conecto las señales al socket (readyRead y disconnected). 
Cuando quiero escribir en el socket lo recupero de la tabla hash y cuando recibo en el socket me lleva a slotReadyRead() donde proceso el buffer:

```
void Class::slotReadyRead()
{
    QTcpSocket *socket = static_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
    QByteArray *buffer = buffers.value(socket);
    while (socket->bytesAvailable()>0)
    {
        buffer->append(socket->readAll());
    }
    QByteArray bufferCons = *buffer;
}
```

Todo esto está funcionando correctamente en mi entorno de desarrollo (máquina virtual con Debian 9). Pero cuando lo instalo en la máquina real de forma aleatoria me sale ese warning:

```
qsocketnotifier: invalid socket <nro del socket> and type 'Read', disabling..
```

Y me cierra la comunicación con el cliente. No soy capaz de encontrar el problema, he instalado el entorno de desarrollo en el ordenador de producción y compilado directamente desde ahí y sigue haciéndolo. Solo funciona bien en máquina virtual, he probado en más máquinas virtuales y funciona, pero cuando lo llevo a máquina real, me da ese fallo.

Answer (score 0):

Al final resultó que no era problema del socket, estaba usando una librería de modbus y ésta en algún momento debía desbordar la pila o algo y me machacaba el socket, que no tenía nada que ver. Una vez eliminada esa librería, sin cambiar nada más, el socket se mantiene abierto sin problema.El porqué funcionaba bien en máquina virtual y mal en máquina real, quedará en la incógnita, misterios de la vida XD.